# Java File not being detected in IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, file-not-found

I am missing some basic funda here... intelliJ IDE doesn't detect the DefaultDataLayer.java. As we can see in the image the file is in same project. Appreciate help on what is missing ?[Image of intelliJ IDE throwing error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebGZy.png)

When I delete and recreate the package and class, they are now visible to App.java, but frustrated of the restart solution.

Comment: What IDE? There is more than one IDE for working in Java.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA is IDE.

Comment: Don't tell me in a comment where it isn't easily visible. Instead, [edit] your question and include a tag for it.

Comment: Did you forget to add an `import` statement for it?